# Not able to deploy Flask python web app using mod_wsgi (Apache)

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask, apache2, mod-wsgi

I've developed a python flask web app and tried to host in a linux (ubuntu 12.04) machine using mod_wsgi (Apache). But am not able to access the application as client web browser showing Internal server error.

On checking the apache error log, noticed the following error.

```
[Wed May 10 16:08:11 2017] [error] [client 192.168.160.101]   File "/var/www/FlaskApp/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/http.py", line 28, in <module>
[Wed May 10 16:08:11 2017] [error] [client 192.168.160.101]     from urllib.request import parse_http_list as _parse_list_header
[Wed May 10 16:08:11 2017] [error] [client 192.168.160.101] ImportError: No module named request
```

In my system, both python2.7 and python 3.6(anaconda) installed and both python --version and pip -V shows different python interpreter, Is this mismatch in python interpreters caused the issue. I've written the code in python2.x mode.

```
ccptriage@ccptriage-ThinkCentre-M72e:/var/www/FlaskApp/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages$ python --version
Python 2.7.6

ccptriage@ccptriage-ThinkCentre-M72e:/var/www/FlaskApp/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages$ pip -V
pip 9.0.1 from /home/ccptriage/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages (python 3.6)
```

My apache config file is as follows,
**/etc/apache2/sites-available/FlaskApp**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName  TVMTELXSI
     ServerAdmin vysakh
     #WSGIDaemonProcess FlaskApp threads=5
     WSGIDaemonProcess FlaskApp python-path=/var/www/FlaskApp:/var/www/FlaskApp/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages
     WSGIProcessGroup FlaskApp
     WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/FlaskApp/flaskapp.wsgi
     <Directory /var/www/FlaskApp/>
      WSGIProcessGroup FlaskApp
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
     </Directory>
     ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
     LogLevel warn
     CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

Could you please have someone help me to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Verify what version of mod_wsgi is compiled for.

- http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/checking-your-installation.html#python-installation-in-use

This needs to be the same as what you want to use.

Also revise how you are using Python virtual environments and use the recommended methods.

- http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/virtual-environments.html

Using `python-path` with `site-packages` is not the recommended way.

The virtual environment must be the same Python version as mod_wsgi is compiled for.